# CodeIgniter 3 - using form_validation on raw POST requests?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm currently writing up a small API for an existing application that currently uses form_validation to validate that fields such as

```
'username', 'email' have the flags ala "required", "valid_email" etc.
```

However, it seems that form_validation is specifically for form data, and has no interest in parsing through data that I load in from input->post.

As an example, this is what I've tried using;

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$this->form_validation->set_rules($name, 'Name', 'required');
```

Is there any solution that allows you to use `form_validation` for raw `POST` data? Or a similar library for handling this data?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this as I found the solution.

It turns out that `form_validation` doesn't care at all if you're submitting via a form or not - it checks for the field's name in `input->post` as standard.

i.e: Sending through a CURL request with the POST key `'name'` populated with `'myname123'` will be accepted as standard by `form_validation('name', 'friendly-name', 'ruleset'`).